# Help with a sub-space question. How do I know that the sequence is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following are subspaces of R^∞

**v = (v, 1, v, 1, v, 1, . . .):** This not in the sequence, since there will be a 2 every other component.

**All sequences in R^∞ whose components are 0 from some
point on.**

This is apparantely a subspace in R. I understand that all the zeroes that come after are in R,however how do we know that before the 0 components, the sequence doesnt look like the **v** sequence or some other sequence that doesnt work a subspace with itself?

Comment: If the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, it is a subspace.  Can you verify these two properties?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse the elements of $\Bbb R^\infty$ (which are the sequences) with subsets (subspaces) of these. We never ask or state whether a *single vector* forms a subspace or not.

In the first example, the following subset is considered:
$$\{(x,1,x,1,x,1,\dots) \, :\, x\in\Bbb R\}$$
This is not a subspace, besides others because it doesn't contain the zero vector (the zero sequence).

On the other hand, $\{(x,0,x,0,x,0,\dots) : x\in\Bbb R\}$ *is* a subspace.

So is the other given example $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) :\exists n\forall m\ge n\, (x_m=0)\}$.
Say sequence $a$ has all its nonzero coordinates among the first $n$ and $b$ among the first $n'$, and set $n'':=\max(n, n')$ which satisfies $v_m=0$ if $m>n''$, for every  linear combination $v$ of $a$ and $b$.